# Tailwind, Vue problem with non-English characters when using tags right after eachother

Tags: css, vue.js, tailwind-css, font-face, tailwind-3

I am facing an issue when using tags right after eachother(ex: `span`, 'a' and 'p').
characters merge with each other, although they are in seperate html tags!

How can I prevent that from happing?

```html
    <a href="" class="underline mx-1">حریم شخصی</a>
    <a href="">استفاده</a>

    <span>حریم</span>
    <span>استفاده</span>
    <span>حریم</span>
```

**Codepen**: https://codepen.io/blackcrowxyz/pen/jOZOZoR

What I want:(استفاده حریم is right)
[image]

What I get:(استفادهحریم is wrong)
[image]

sample output:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use `&nbsp;` because every character in between tags, will prevent the issue from happening.

```html
    <span>قوانین و شرایط استفاده</span>
    &nbsp;
    <span>حریم شخصی</span>
```

result:

[image]

Comment: YOu can use tailwind css properties also.Also, I am not able to see some letters in the code while they are in pictures.

Comment: I have added the [codepen](https://codepen.io/blackcrowxyz/pen/jOZOZoR) link as well in question description!

Answer (score 0):

Is this the way you want?

**Using flex**

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="p-4 w-64 flex justify-between">
  <span><a href="#">
    قوانین و شرایط استفاده
    </a></span>
    <span><a href="#">حریم شخصی</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

**Using margin**

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="p-4">
  <span><a href="#" class="ml-5">
    قوانین و شرایط استفاده
    </a></span>
    <span><a href="#">حریم شخصی</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems to be ok in your code snippet, but there a codepen provided in the question detail, as you can see there, characters are merged! and the correct form is under it. I don't know if its a vue problem or tailwind!!

Comment: Just post in the question part that what you've done and what you want with screenshot/code.